# Why doesn't my Nginx www redirection work?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have this configuration:

```
server {
listen         80;
server_name    example.com www.example.com;
return 301 https://example.fr$request_uri;
}


server {
listen 443 ssl;

root /var/www/example_v2/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

server_name example.com www.example.com;

return 301 https://example.fr$request_uri;

}
```

When I go to `example.com`, it redirects me correctly to `example.fr`, but when I go to `www.example.com`, it doesn't. My DNS for `example.com` and `www.example.com` go to the same IP.

What could be going wrong?

EDIT: curl

```
➜  ~ curl -L -I example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 11:50:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://example.fr/

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 11:50:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 40538
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

➜  ~ curl -L -I www.example.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 11:50:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 176
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Sep 2016 16:27:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "57dacbed-b0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: please show output of curl -L -I for example.com and www.example.com. It looks like your config is valid.

Comment: @Navern I add it to the post.

Comment: I believe you have somewhere configured wildcard(*.example.com)/or another server block with www.example.com and that's why you don't have redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted configuration, nginx is performing correctly.

The following blocks should be one way to ahieve what you are trying to do:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/server.key;
    return 301 https://example.fr$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/server.key;
    return 301 https://www.example.fr$request_uri;
}
```

My experience is that not including the appropriate SSL configuration in a forwarding server block will result in https://example.com and https://www.example.com causing browser trust warnings without redirection.